# The fiber bundle given by a cocycle.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-bundles

I'm studing this [notes](https://www.math.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/~mabreu/GD/RLF-notes.pdf), and I have a question about the contruction in the proposition 23.5, page 185. The statement is:

> Let $\{g_{αβ} \}$ be a cocycle subordinates to an open cover ${U_α }$
>   of $M$ . There exists a vector bundle $ξ = (π, E, M )$, that admits a
>   trivialization $\{φ_α \}$ for which the transition functions are the
>   $\{g_{αβ} \}$.

In the proof, he claims:

$E=\cup_{\alpha \in A}(U_\alpha\times\mathbb{R}^r)\Big/\sim$ is a differentiable manifold with the relation gives by $(p,v)\sim (q,w)$ iff $p=q$ and $\exists$ $\alpha, \beta \in A$ such that $g_{αβ}w=v$.

**My question is**: Why $E$ is a manifold? Does Anyone have some hints about how can I find the charts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Let $V^{\prime}=\coprod_{\alpha} (\alpha \times U_\alpha \times \mathbb R^k)/\sim$ where $(\beta,x, \mathbb R^k) \sim (\alpha,x,g_{\alpha\beta})$ and
$$q:\coprod_{\alpha} (\alpha \times U_\alpha \times \mathbb R^k) \to V^{\prime} $$
be the quotient map.

Note that $q$ is a continuous open map and the restriction to each $(\alpha \times U_\alpha \times \mathbb R^k)$ denoted $q_\alpha$ is injective, we have that 
$$\left(q_\alpha(\alpha \times U_\alpha \times \mathbb R^k),q_\alpha^{-1}\right)$$
gives a chart.

details can actually be found in [these](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~azinger/mat566-spr15/vectorbundles.pdf) set of notes actually (same notation is used.)

Comment: Thanks! Is $q$ the quotient map instead of the projection?

Comment: @LeonardoSchultz yes of course. Sorry about that!